# How to run a report in a site collection that lists every site w/ users - Full Control

Tags: pnp-powershell

We are implementing a SharePoint based Knowledge Base.  In each site collection, we need to deploy one or more "Knowledge Libraries" ... This is a document library that has a group of users with Contribute rights.  Additionally, the library has Domain/users read access, so the search engine can pick up the content.

How can I run a report on each site collection to get a list of sites w/ corresponding Site Owners, so I can have a Site Owner set up Knowledge Libraries as needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the site collections using Get-PnPTenantSite , iterate each and Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin will get you the site collection admins, as shown here:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-get-all-site-collection-administrators-from-sharepoint-online-site-collections-using-pnp-powershell

Comment: Hi Kasper, can you advise on rather than getting site collection info, rather drill into one site for subsites and their owners?  It seems there must be a corresponding  PnP commandlet for Get-PnPSiteCollectionAdmin  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Martin. As far as I know only Site Collections have an owner , so I wonder how and where you specify the owner of a sub site?

Comment: Kasper. I see what you are saying about "owner" of a sub site.  Is it possible to iterate through a site collections sub-sites and print users that have Full Control?

Comment: Sort of, but that might include AD-groups